# How to pass vararg as array to function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, variadic-functions

I want to pass vararg from the buy function to the drive function
but I get

a compile error:

```
required Array<T> found Array<out T>
```

code:

```
class Car

fun buy(vararg cars: Car) {
    drive(cars) //compile error
}

fun drive(cars: Array<Car>) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution would be to change `drive` to `fun drive(Array<out Car>) { ... }`.  This of course means that the cars inside drive cannot be modified but avoids the copying.

Answer (score 37):

The precise error is:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Array<Car>
Found:    Array<out Car>
```

The problem is that when you have a `vararg cars: Car` function parameter, its type inside the function is `Array<out Car>`, which basically represents a read-only array of the arguments the function was called with - after all, it wouldn't really be a nice thing to start modifying the arguments you got as a `vararg` (function parameters in Kotlin are read-only `val`s, and this is something very similar).

But your `drive` function requires a regular `Array<Car>`, which of course is writable as well. So if you wish to keep these function signatures, you'll need to create a new array that contains everything from your read-only array. This can be created using the following syntax:

```
drive(arrayOf(*cars))
```

This calls the `arrayOf` function we usually create arrays with, which takes a vararg parameter, and uses the spread operator which is a way to pass in the elements of an array (which `cars` is, inside the `buy` function) as the vararg parameters ([docs here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)).

While all this may sound complicated, it's actually a very efficient solution, as it just uses `Array.copyOf` under the hood in the bytecode.

Comment: I think the other answer is more typical, that you would favory `Array<out Car>` as the parameter for the second function, not make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun foo(vararg strings: String): Array<out String> {
    return strings
}

//  Define a var 
var yourVar: Array<out String> = foo("a", "b", "c")

// Use var in Java method `public void javaMethod(String... someParam)() {}`
javaMethod(*yourVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun checkMatch(vararg cards: SetsCard): Int {
    return if (isSet(*cards)) 16 else -2
}

private fun isSet(vararg cards: SetsCard) : Boolean {
    if (cards.size == 3) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Essencially you need the vararg keywork before the variable name.

```
fun args(vararg cars: Car) {
   //use cars as an array 
}
```

Comment: even if you want to add it to the second function, this will not fix the compile error.