# Why Kotlin's Type's vararg is treated as Array<out Type> and not Array<Type>

Tags: generics, kotlin, variadic-functions

The following method gets compiled in Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        varargMethod(1, 2.0);
    }

    static void varargMethod(Number... va) {
        arrayMethod(va);
    }

    static void arrayMethod(Number[] arr) {
        for (Number number : arr) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to write similar code in Kotlin i get type mismatch error:

```
fun main() {
    varargFun(1, 2.0)
}

fun varargFun(vararg va: Number) {
    arrayFun(va) // Error:(6, 14) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<out Number> but Array<Number> was expected
}

fun arrayFun(arr: Array<Number>) {
    arr.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

I expected `va` to be of type `Array<String>`, but it is `Array<out String>`. If I cast it: `va as Array<Number>`, I get a warning:

> Warning:(6, 21) Kotlin: Unchecked cast: Array to Array

How am I supposed to pass `vararg` as an `Array` to another function without getting warning and errors?

Comment: You could declare your array function as `fun arrayFun(arr: Array<out Number>)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that in Java arrays are covariant, i.e. the following is valid:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number[] numbers = new Number[0];
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[0];

    numbers = ints;
}
```

However, arrays are not covariant in Kotlin, i.e. the following gives a compilation error:

```
var numbers: Array<Number> = arrayOf()
val ints: Array<Int> = arrayOf()

numbers = ints // error: required Array<Number>, found Array<Int>
```

However you can declare the array is a producer (i.e. you promise you'll never insert anything inside it; the compiler will make sure of that) with the keyword `out`. That makes the array covariant, i.e. the following is valid:

```
var numbers: Array<out Number> = arrayOf() // we will only extract Numbers out of this array
val ints: Array<Int> = arrayOf()

numbers = ints // this is ok
```

Given that, if `vararg va: Number` was not treated as a `Array<out Number>`, then you could have called your method only with `Number` objects and not with its subclasses. I.e., the following would fail:

```
fun main() {
    varargFun(arrayOf<Int>(1, 2)) // error: required Array<Number>, found Array<Int>
}

fun varargFun(va: Array<Number>) {
    arrayFun(va)
}
```

But again, with an `out` (which is what `vararg` does), it magically works:

```
fun main() {
    varargFun(arrayOf<Int>(1, 2))
}

fun varargFun(va: Array<out Number>) {
    arrayFun(va)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[This is covered in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> Inside a function a `vararg`-parameter of type `T` is visible as an array of `T`, i.e. the [...] variable in the example above has type `Array<out T>`.

The solution to your problem is simple: ignore Kotlin's guard rails, and [copy the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090336/3133286).

```
fun varargFun(vararg va: Number) {
    val copy = arrayOf(*va)
    arrayFun(copy)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a waste though? The array is already created for you, and you create a whole new one and need to copy all content into it. Why can't you use it directly, like on Java?